# Como guardar pdf

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Como puedo guardar un archivo .PDF en /my_folder con la fecha actual como nombre de archivo?

```
    val date = Date()
    val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy  HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(date)
    val dir = "${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}/my_folder"
    File(dir).mkdirs()
    val outpath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/my_folder" +
            File.separator + timeStamp +".pdf"

    val document = Document()

    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, FileOutputStream(outpath))
    document.open()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando las clases:

`import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;`

```
package nuevopdf;


import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
public class CrearPdf2 {

        // TODO code application logic here
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    public String archivo = System.getProperty("user.dir") +"/"+ df.format(new Date()) + ".pdf";

  public void NuevoPdf(){

    Document documento = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 80, 80, 75, 75);

    //writer es declarado como el método utilizado para escribir en el archivo
    PdfWriter writer = null;

    try {      
      //Obtenemos la instancia del archivo a utilizar
      writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(documento, new FileOutputStream(archivo));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException|DocumentException ex) {
      ex.getMessage();
    }

    //Abrimos el documento para edición
    documento.open();

    //Declaramos un texto como Paragraph
    //Le podemos dar formado como alineación, tamaño y color a la fuente.
    Paragraph parrafo = new Paragraph();
    parrafo.setAlignment(Paragraph.ALIGN_CENTER);
    parrafo.setFont(FontFactory.getFont("Sans",20,Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE));
    parrafo.add("CUALQUIER COSA");

    try {
      //Agregamos el texto al documento
      documento.add(parrafo);
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
      ex.getMessage();
    }

    documento.close(); //Cerramos el documento
    writer.close(); //Cerramos writer
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Llamamos por el método para generar el pdf
    new CrearPdf2().NuevoPdf();
  }
}
```

Recuerda agregar el .jar de pdf a la biblioteca del proyecto, en mi caso use **itextpdf-5.3.3.jar**